# redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to point *www.mydomain.example/blogs* to *www.anotherdomain.example/blog.html* and still keep the URL the same, any ideas?

I have tried so many different methods and the URL changes to the URL im am redirecting to.

Thanks

Comment: If domain 2 runs on another server than domain 1, this is not trivial. Do you have access to your web server's configuration?

Comment: i have cpanel and access to the root file system as well

Answer (score 1):

Unless both domains are hosted on the same server and you have access via the file system, you will probably need a [proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on *mydomain.example* that forwards the requests to *anotherdomain.example*, fetched the response and forwards it back to the client.

Comment: I do have access via the file system in this case

Comment: @Wright-Geek: You could set up *blogs* as an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) of *blog.html*.